# 1 штука карандашей

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

"1 штука карандашей" - правильно ли?

Comment: Надо думать, что речь о цитате? Приведите источник.

Answer (score 1):

Вот одно из значений слова "штука":

> ШТУКА, -и; ж. [от нем. Stuck] 1. (обычно с колич. сл.). Отдельный предмет из числа однородных, считаемых. Купи штук пять апельсинов. Сколько осталось сигарет? - Две штуки. Розы по двенадцать рублей за штуку. У тебя рубашек десять штук ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x))

В словаре приведены примеры корректного употребления слова *штука*. При этом я считаю неграмотным (в лучшем случае просторечным) такие выражения как "две (три, четыре) штуки карандашей" вместо "два (три, четыре) карандаша", "пять (шесть, семь и т. д. ) штук карандашей" вместо "пять (шесть, семь и т. д. ) карандашей" и в особенности — "одна штука карандашей" вместо "один карандаш".

Давайте рассмотрим пример из словаря: "Купи штук пять апельсинов". Эта фраза построена корректно, в ней "штук пять" говорит о приблизительном количестве. Но "Купи пять штук апельсинов" я считаю неверным, следует писать "Купи пять апельсинов".

Comment: Почему некорректно? Карандаши - однородные, считаемые предметы.

Comment: @Сибиряк Я изменил ответ, теперь стало яснее?

Comment: Почему "рубашек десять штук" вы считаете корректным, а "пять штук карандашей" – нет.

Answer (score 0):

ШТУКА (целый, нетронутый, непочатый ещё рулон ткани) — старая мера длины, не имеющая определённого значения; ткань в куске, равном в среднем 48 локтям.
Карандаш же — отдельный штучный предмет — не представляет собой часть «карандашной массы» или длины: в производстве подготовленные для разрезки заготовки называют блоками карандашей, а готовые карандаши упаковывают в коробки и, как правило, делают это вручную во избежание повреждения каждого карандаша, так что и на этом этапе исключается возникновение термина «штука карандашей».